# Dell9550: bluetooth headset connects and then disconnects in a couple of seconds

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

Anyone has a solution to this?

On initial install, my headset wasn't identified/found at all. After adding the missing middleware and setting AutoEnable=true in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf, the headset was identified and I was able to use it once.
But the very next day I tried to reconnect, and it doesn't work any longer. The device connects successfully, I can hear a notification in the headset, and them it disconnects shortly afterwards(3-5 seconds).

What should I try next?

Answer (score 5):

Go into bluetoothctl and set your device to trust

```
# bluetoothctl
# devices
    Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
# trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Then I rebooted and the device worked fine. This was probably the 15th fix I tried for the numerous issues connecting my bluetooth headset so hopefully this works!

Answer (score 2):

**had the following issues on ubuntu 18.04 with dell xps 13 9370**

- bluetooth headset connects and then disconnects in a couple of seconds
- when trying to pair with blueman "Device added successfully, but failed to connect"
- and I would never have the option to select my headphones in the sound settings.

**did the following steps to fix it:**

- upgrade blueman

  sudo apt upgrade blueman
- unpair headphones

go into Ubuntu Settings > Bluetooth
click on my bluetooth headphones > remove

- pair headphones with blueman

put my headphones into pairing mode
open blueman in sys tray and click on setup new device, select headphones, go through steps (put "headset" as device type)

Answer (score 0):

For me, using Blueman helped. You can install it with `sudo apt install blueman`.

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.

Comment: @Videonauth, thank You for Your suggestion. I may try doing it in my spare time.

Comment: @Videonauth I had similar question about details, but on the other hand tried to install. After installation, restarted my Dell Laptop and problem stopped, I think you may try this. (Also note that my OS is Ubuntu 18)

Answer (score 0):

What helped me in the end is trying different approaches from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1574324, including a custom PPA from Luke.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Linux Mint 19, my headphone is a Sony MDR-XB650BT and my laptop is a Dell Inspiron 7000. I have been fighting all day to make this phone work with my laptop and no solution ever worked.

I was able to pair but seconds after the phone disconnected. I found the solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258074/error-when-trying-to-connect-to-bluetooth-speaker-org-bluez-error-failed

Summarizing: Install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth!

You can find more details in the answer over here.

Answer (score 0):

For me, simply removing the device and re-pairing it did the trick:
Settings -> Bluetooth -> name_of_device -> Remove Device.
Then put the device in pairing mode and reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens in ubuntu 20.04/ mint 20. There is some problem with the device registration, probably associated to bluez. It could work fine the first time after a fresh start, which's the reason why some users report that there is no problem in a live session after booting from USB. The walk-around is to erase the bluetooth cache before connecting the device with something like this:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/bluetooth/[controller_address]/cache/[device_address]
```

To avoid doing this each time the machine reboots, I added the script to crontab to have a provisional solution.